# jvm parameters not visible with in arquillian testcase on jboss

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I am running arquillian in the jboss managed container mode.
I am setting the following jvm parameters while starting arquillian testcases in arquillian.xml file:

```
<property name="javaVmArguments">-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=629 -Djboss.bind.address.unsecure=127.0.0.1
```

However, in my testcode, I am unable to see these jvm parameters.
When the following code executes in the testcase, it returns "Not set".

```
System.getProperty("jboss.bind.address.unsecure", "Not set"));
```

My testcase looks like this:

```
@Test
    @InSequence(2)
    @OperateOnDeployment("PIB")
    public void testDeployCamelEngineService() throws Exception {
        this.deployer.deploy("CamelEngine");
        changeConfigParameters("med_service_protocol_info", "CM");
    }
```

I am using some JVM parameters in the changeConfigParameters method .

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: how does you test look like? Are you using @RunAsClient ?

Comment: updated the question with testcode. thanks

Comment: is there any way to pass JVM parameter to remote container ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this property sets the arguments for the jvm that the container is deployed on, not for the vm that is running the tests.